# Remove middle number from multiple files and copy

Tags: batch, file-transfer, trim

I have the multiple PDF files in the specific format in a specific folder and for those particular files I need to trim the middle number using bat file and move to the destination folder with the new name.

**Detail**

- **Source folder:** `C:/roger/brawn`
- **Destination:** `D:/var/lag`
- **File Format:** `eAWI_12345678_89101112_01Mar2018.pdf`

**Desired Result**

I need to trim the **`89101112`** from the original source file name 
 and get a result of `eAWI_12345678_01Mar2018.pdf`

This file name number format gets generated dynamically using variables in an application.

Comment: What's up with the status of this now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop and set the underscore character in the file names as a delimiter. You can use tokens `1,2,3,*` to later concatenate variables to build and parse the source and destination file name accordingly for later use with the [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command to get the desired result.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON
SET Source=c:/roger/brawn
SET Destination=D:/var/lag
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3,* DELIMS=_" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%source%\*.pdf"') DO ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%source%\%%F_%%G_%%H_%%I" "%Destination%\%%F_%%G_%%I" && IF EXIST "%Destination%\%%F_%%G_%%I" DEL /Q /F "%source%\%%F_%%G_%%H_%%I"
EXIT
```

**Note:** The [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) command pipes an `F` to the [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command so it implicitly selects `F` for "file" since it explicitly specifies the new destination file name parsing the 3rd token in the loop to help get the desired file name. The [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command is followed by the [conditional execution (&&)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) confirming it was successful and then it confirms the existence of the new destination file before it deletes the original source file.

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [ECHO](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [DEL](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)